# Вызов защищённого конструктора в разных версиях языка

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++17, c++20

```
struct A { 
protected: 
    A() {}; 
};

struct B : A { 
    B() = default;
} b{};

int main() {}
```

Почему этот код работает с 11 и 20 стандартом, но не работает с /std:c++17?

> error C2248: 'A::A': cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'
>
> note: see declaration of 'A::A'
>
> note: see declaration of 'A'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656093/changed-rules-for-protected-constructors-in-c17

Answer (score 1):

Потому что во всех 3 стандартах менялось определение аггрегата и в соответствии с этим определением менялись виды инициализации, которые проходят в данном случае. В конфигурации определений 17 стандарта выполняется аггрегатная инициализация, которая не позволяет вызвать защищённый конструктор и возникает ошибка.